# Chat seems to be borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Any attempt to access chat is redirecting me to an [error page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/):

[image: Error page]

Is there some sort of maintenance or upgrade going on?

Comment: I just got [something very similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/367808/chat-seems-to-be-borked) when trying to load this meta question. I haven't seen that again on further attempts to load meta pages, but the chat errors are consistent.

Comment: Seems like Chat.SE is down now too

Comment: Confirm that chat.SE is down, but chat.meta.SE is still up.

Comment: It's not just SO. Chats are dieing all over SE. Maybe we should have a question for it on SE meta, but, I'm not sure if that counts as a duplicate?

Comment: @Cosmo One now exists on MSE: [Chat Seems to be Down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310167)

Comment: Update: it lives, somehow?

Comment: @Cosmo Yep, all three chat servers appear to be up.

Comment: All the servers are now up. This was a server-side downtime.

Comment: Suggest to  display relevant message rather than display error .

Answer (score 12):

As Tom mentioned on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310173/164200), we have solved the problem short-term and Chat is back up. We'll be working on a long-term solution as well as a postmortem.

Comment: What will the long-term solution and the postmortem be (you are also staff, so you may know better)

Comment: Bigger hard disk. @Mulliganaceous

Comment: @Mulliganaceous Short version, we need to get larger disk drives or make more space on the existing ones.

Comment: I hear they just finished a new two feet wide hard drive prototype, should be sufficient.